# What is the consistency steps of a recursive function?

Tags: r

I am finding inconsistency in recursive function examples, so I need help clarifying its workings.

This recursive function has the argument x value be returned along with function fracrec. This fracrec gets multiplied by the original value of x. The value of it is whatever the parenthesis gives x-1 . It repeats until it exits at x == 0. Meaning that the x portion and '*' of return is the "formula" and what is used for every round.

```
facrec <- function(x){
  if(x==0){
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(x*facrec(x-1))  
  }
}
```

Now take this next one and there isn't anything like x and '*'. So I then look at it differently since myfibrec(5) gives '5'. Taking the absolute value of the first pass would be 4+3 and already surpassing 5 with more passes still to go. There isn't any formula to go off of, so I am having difficulty understanding how the 5 came about. In the above I used the formula to be 'x' and '*', which I'll admit its odd and probably incorrect.

```
myfibrec <- function(n) {
  if(n==1||n==2){
    return(1)
  }else{
    return(myfibrec(n-1)+myfibrec(n-2))
  }
}
```

In yet another one, below it treats the value in the argument as the formula. This gives 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

```
function Count (integer N)
    if (N <= 0) return "Must be a positive integer";
    if (N >9 ) return "counting completed";
    else return Count (N+1);
end function
```

Where are all the formulas or math calculations coming from in these recursive functions?

Comment: "Taking the absolute value of the first pass would be 4+3 and already surpassing 5 with more passes still to go". Incorrect. The first pass says to return myfibrec(4)+myfibrec(3). Google the fibbonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

for 'facrec' google "factorial"

for 'myfibrec' google "Fibonacci"

last one seems to be java code, not R